# How should I use `create time` command in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I wonder if Apache IoTDB time series database need to set a field using "create time"? I know IoTDB is able to support this command, but I wonder If necessary, what may be the scenarios that I need to use this `create time` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if your scenario need to revise your data and time it was inserted. If you need to change any details in time range of data, then you can use `create time` command in Apache IoTDB.